# Removing older versions of Command Line Tools

Tags: xcode, command-line-interface, xcode-command-line-tools

I was analyzing my files with CleanMyMac's space lens tool, and found multiple versions of command line tools in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.
Is it safe to remove the older versions? I don't use Xcode or Android Studio, so can I completely uninstall the command line tools?

[image: Command Line Tools]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Originally answered [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253425286?answerId=256408798022#256408798022).

If you are using any package manager (e.g. homebrew), then you need the command line tools.
Here is my current SDK for macOS Monterey 12.0.1:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you uninstall the command line tools, and some software you are using is dependent on them, then they (or the latest version) can just be re-installed.